# Slider binding causes significant performance drop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, controls

As the title says I have a custom slider declared like this:

```
<customControls:ThumbDragSlider IsEnabled="{Binding PlayerSourceState}"
                                Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Slider}}"
                                Value="{Binding CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.Position, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={converters:SecondsToTimeSpanConverter}}"/>
```

There are couple more properties that being set, more events and some commands binding too, but I've omitted them, because I've narrowed down the performance issue to this specific line:

```
Value="{Binding CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.Position, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={converters:SecondsToTimeSpanConverter}}"
```

Removing it also removes all the lag. On my PC it runs just fine, but when tested on an older machine without a GPU, using only the CPU as such, it doesn't run well. This slider is used to navigate through a `MediaElement` and the lag is most prevalent on the actual media file, it even shutters.

The converter is declared as follows:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(TimeSpan))]
public class SecondsToTimeSpanConverter : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is TimeSpan ts)
        {
            return ts;
        }
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)value);
    }
}
```

And the custom slider like this:

```
public class ThumbDragSlider : Slider
{
    public event DragStartedEventHandler DragStarted;
    public event DragCompletedEventHandler DragCompleted;
    public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> ThumbMouseEnter;

    public new TimeSpan Value
    {
        get => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(base.Value);
        set => base.Value = value.TotalSeconds;
    }

    public ThumbDragSlider()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        var track = this.GetElementFromTemplate<Track>("PART_Track");
        track.Thumb.MouseEnter += (o, args) => ThumbMouseEnter?.Invoke(o, args);
    }

    protected override void OnThumbDragStarted(DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnThumbDragStarted(e);
        DragStarted?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected override void OnThumbDragCompleted(DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnThumbDragCompleted(e);
        DragCompleted?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Every 250ms a timer event is being fired to synchronize the slider value with the `MediaElement` value, the binding cant do that because the `MediaElement` doesn't have a `DependencyProperty` responsible for the `Position`, nor there is `INotifyPropertyChanged` event that is being fired.

The eventhandler of the System.Timers.Timer:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => sMovieSkipSlider.Value =
    ViewModel.CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.Position);
```

What could be causing the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: @glenebob Removing the binding causes problems such as whenever the slider's thumb is being dragged, the media element is not being updated.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. Two way bindings are not removed by a direct property update as I suggested.

Comment: Since, both the slider value and the media element position are in TimeSpan, why is the converter required?

Comment: Also, I would suggest to set the value of Media Element position in the drag completed event and remove the binding all together.

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota see for your first comment [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50116192/5687778).

Comment: @Deadzone Did the second comment work?

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota it will work, but while dragging the media won't update and user won't know where is he dragging

Comment: @Deadzone, I believe the `ConvertBack` method of your `SecondsToTimeSpanConverter` is wrong. This might be unrelated to your problem but I still wanted to point this out. Shouldn't this method return a **double**?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the need for creating a custom slider. I believe this could be achieved by using the regular slider.

You stated the following:

> Every 250ms a timer event is being fired to synchronize the slider value with the `MediaElement` value, the binding cant do that because the `MediaElement` doesn't have a `DependencyProperty` responsible for the `Position`, nor there is `INotifyPropertyChanged` event that is being fired.

Then there is no point of using a binding, you can simply handle the `MouseLeftButtonUpEvent`of your slider and set the `Position` of your `MediaElement` that way. 
Perhaps a timer that updates every 250ms might also be too fast, of course this depends on your requirements. Like if you're planning to use this with high precision. But if you just want a simple player then an update every 1s should be more than enough.

Here is an example of initializing the timer that updates your slider:

```
private TimeSpan TotalTime;
private DispatcherTimer MediaTimer;

private void CurrentMediaPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TotalTime = CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
    MediaTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    MediaTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    //If 1 second is too slow, change this to: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)
    MediaTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MediaTimer_Tick);
    MediaTimer.Start();
}

private void MediaTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds > 0)
    {
        if (TotalTime.TotalSeconds > 0)
        {
            sMovieSkipSlider.Value = CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.Position.TotalSeconds /
                                   TotalTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Add the `MouseLeftButtonUpEventHandler` to your slider:

```
sMovieSkipSlider.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(sMovieSkipSlider_MouseLeftButtonUp), true);
```

Here is an example of handling the event to update the `Position`  of your `MediaElement`:

```
private void sMovieSkipSlider_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (TotalTime.TotalSeconds > 0)
    {
        CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sMovieSkipSlider.Value * TotalTime.TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

---

*Comment*: I've probabaly messed up some of your MVVM setup, but this should at least push you in the right direction. You can always work with the `DataContext` property of your view where needed.

Comment: I think handling the MouseLeftButtonUp will have the same problem as removing the binding. While dragging the media won't update and user won't know where is he dragging!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a delay for the binding?

```
Value="{Binding CurrentMediaPlayer.MediaElement.Position, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={converters:SecondsToTimeSpanConverter}, Delay=50}"
```

Maybe you have to play a bit around with different values.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't setting the Value cause the binding to trigger and update the media player's position, but since a few milliseconds elapse until all this happens the media player jumps back just a little bit causing stutter? I would take steps to not update the media player position during the synchronization.